# clear form values with reset button

Tags: forms, button, reset

Alright I could use a small tip here:
I have a form with two buttons, one has to submit the form and the other one has to reset the complete form.
The text - field keeps its value after every submit, but I would like to clear it completely with the reset button

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="Clear Me Please">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

---

I have a input field, submit button and a reset button. Upon submiting the form the user input will be inserted as value, because I dont want to lose the input.   Now, when I type something into the field I can reset the form as planed, but after submiting the value now stays as supposed, but pressing the reset button resets the input to the value.

**Example:** I type in "TEXT", press Reset, gets reseted to "". Type "TEXT2", press Submit, gets submited, put in as value, field has now "TEXT2" written in. Replace "TEXT2" with "TEXT3", press Reset, now field contains "TEXT2" instead of "". I hope this is explaination enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may a little bit more you have to do

But his may help-Using Jquery

```
Edited Version:
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#btn").on('click', function(e)
      {
        document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        $('#input').attr("value", "");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="<?= $_POST['input'] ?>"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <input type="button" id="btn"  value="Reset">
 </form>
```

---

```
 Orginal Version:
 <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
            jQuery("#btn").on('click', function(e)
            {   
               values= $('#fname').val();
                document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
                $('#fname').attr("placeholder", values);
            });
        });
    </script>
        <head>
    <form id="myForm">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
      <input type="button" id="btn"  value="Reset form">
    </form>
```

jsfiddle link[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgL262nd/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortionally this doesnt work in my case, because I need the submited value as value. The form should keep your text after submiting.

Comment: The submit puts the input text back into the input as value.
But I want to delete everything in the fields without the site reloading.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but it's still not quite doing what I want :)
Maybe to clarify things a bit more: The text input has a set value (after getting submited the first time), I would like to clear the value, as an example I edited my request post.

Comment: If I use simply placeholder I cannot submit it.

Comment: why? ofcource u can submit because value will not taken from placeholder

Comment: No, I cannot submit the placeholder. I want to submit the given value. The value "Clear Me Please" is given, it has to be submited or cleared.

Comment: obviously u cant submit placeholder but what problem with value.just write value="".user input will automatically inserted to it

Comment: Alright I have added a detailed explanation with example in my request

Comment: Perfect! With a slight change it does exactly what I want :) I've added the solution to your post. Thanks!

Comment: I have downvoted the answer because of the usage of jQuery. The author of the question didn't mention in any way and using jQuery is very much something like a ugly workaround.